# Passing variables from a HTML form to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

One of the submissions in my form is Choose Your Opponent.  It has 425 options based on a data query. The form element is a select list name = 'opponent'.  Here is the line that produces the the User sees.

```
while($opponent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($oresults)) {              
    echo '<option value = "'. $opponent['id'] .'">'. $opponent['school'] .'</option>';          
}
```

The user sees 'school', but it passes 'id' to the PHP.  Is there a way to send both the value and what the option user sees to the PHP?

Only the opponent's 'id' is going into the data table, but I want also send 'school' back to the user saying, "Your stats vs. 'school' has been submitted".

I know I can produce it with another query, but I'd rather not.

Comment: You could but you dont normally need to, just fetch the data again from the database using the ID

Comment: You could have JS do the submission and have all the names in some mapping/object that the JS would read and pass based on selection... Second query seems like much easier solution. `select name from table where id = ?` should take very minimal resources.

Comment: You can use an "unique" value divisor, like `<option value = "'. $opponent['id'] .'#'.$opponent['school'].'">` then you can retrieve again when processing form result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly That makes sense.  I'll definitely work on that and report back.

Comment: *"I know I can produce it with another query, but I'd rather not."*, why not? You should never trust any user inputs. User can for example change `<option value = "id;whateverisinschool">whateverisinschool</option>` to `<option value = "id;somethingreallyinappropriate">whateverisinschool</option>` and then send the form. Then on your next page you would show *somethingreallyinappropriate*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put both the `id` and the `school` in the option value as a string then convert it into an array

```
echo '<option value = "'. $opponent['id'] .','. $opponent['school'] .'">'. $opponent['school'] .'</option>';
```

you will probably receive a string of something like: 'id,school'
next, convert this string into an array. refer to code below

```
$string = 'id,school'     // this is your select option value
$array = explode(',', $string)
```

above code will give you `$array = [ 'id', 'school' ]` which you can now output to your page.

```
echo 'Your stats '. $array[0] .' vs school '. $array[1] .' has been submitted';
```

Comment: Side note: might cause a notice (Undefined Index) when accessing $array[1] if user tinkers with option value (and for example removes the `,`). You could argue and say: well if the user tinkers with the values then its his/her fault. In this case i would say it is justified.

Comment: BillJustin I took RiggsFolly 's lead and coded that out exactly as you answered.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can send JSON with both or all data:

```
echo '<option value="'.htmlentities(json_encode($opponent)).'">'.$opponent['school'].'</option>';
```

Then in PHP:

```
$opponent = json_decode($_POST['opponent'], true);
echo $opponent['school'];
```